# Emma failed, How to debug android test cases running on emulator?

Tags: android, emulation, integration-testing, emma

I am trying to get coverage report by running ant emma on my mavenized android project, everything else went smoothly, but i bumped into NullPointerException when running

```
ant emma debug install test.
```

output is:

```
test:
 [echo] WARNING: Code Coverage is currently only supported on the emulator and rooted devices.
 [echo] Running tests ...
 [exec] 
 [exec] com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2.samples.libraryprojects.mainapp.MainActivityTest:INSTRUMENTATION_RESULT: shortMsg=java.lang.NullPointerException
 [exec] INSTRUMENTATION_RESULT: longMsg=java.lang.NullPointerException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2.samples.libraryprojects.mainapp/com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2.samples.libraryprojects.mainapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
 [exec] INSTRUMENTATION_CODE: 0
 [echo] Downloading coverage file into project directory...
 [exec] remote object '/data/data/com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2.samples.libraryprojects.mainapp/coverage.ec' does not exist
```

How can I debug this ?  I would like to find out where the NPE happened.